# how to convert EST to Other Times Zones(PST/CST/MST) considering Daylight savings C#.NET

Tags: c#, timezone

I have an application in which I am displaying time fields in EST, I need to convert them to respective time zones , DAYLIGHT saving need to be considered.

How can I change to different time zone provided I have EST time and Time Zone to which it needs to get converted

I have to consider Daylight saving On/Off and have to apply Off set.. how can I > any working examples..

Example : I want to convert 3:15 PM which is in EST , needs to be converted to PST

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx

Comment: What have you tried?  And are you sure the source data is fixed to EST and not just in US "Eastern Time" (EST/EDT)?

Comment: Yes data source is fixed to EST

Comment: And.... what have you tried?  If you have tried *nothing*, then your question is not ready for Stack Overflow.  If you are having difficulties, post what you have done so far and we can guide you.

Comment: Also, your question doesn't make logical sense.  A time without a date cannot be converted to a time zone that switches between standard and daylight.  You have to know what date you are talking about to know if daylight time is in effect.  Please edit your question to show what you are attempting to do.

Comment: @MattJohnson, thanks for directing me right direction, I am going through the MSDN to understand how it works....!!

Comment: You may also want to look at [Noda Time](http://www.nodatime.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) to make sure that your DaylightSaving is always right. You can also Convert the DateTimeOffset to different time zone with the [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396765.aspx) static method of the TimeZoneInfo class.