# Convert CST to EST with daylight savings time

Tags: c#, timezone-offset

I'm trying to convert a DateTime that is in CST to EST while adjusting for daylight savings. My local machine is on EST.
Found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769(v=vs.110).aspx) on msdn but user [fokasu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134202/how-to-convert-est-to-other-times-zonespst-cst-mst-considering-daylight-saving)
recommended using DateTimeOffset to adjust for DST, but i dont know how to incorporate that into my code. thanks for any help.
this is what i have so far which works, but i dont think it's adjusting for daylight savings.

```
        DateTime cstTime, utcTime;
        DateTime estTime;
        string cstZoneId, estZoneId;
        TimeZoneInfo cstZone, estZone;

        estZoneId = "Eastern Standard Time";
        cstZoneId = "Central Standard Time";
        estZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(estZoneId);
        cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(cstZoneId);

        //define d as CST
        cstTime = d;
        try
        {
            //convert CST to UTC
            utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(cstTime, cstZone);
            //convert UTC to EST
            estTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, estZone);
            return estTime;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Comment: If you are on EST or CST, then you do not need to worry about daylight saving time.  See http://ericlippert.com/2014/04/14/standard-and-daylight-are-different/.  Furthermore, except for a 1-hour window during the changeover, the difference between Central and Eastern time is one hour.  EST is one hour later than CST, and EDT is one hour later than CDT.

Comment: thank you phoog. it says there that “Eastern Standard Time is not defined as “whatever time it is in New York City right now”, it is defined as “Eastern Time not adjusted for Daylight Saving Time“. so how come i dont have to worry about it ??? is it b/c EST and CST will always be synced when it comes to daylight saving changes ??

Comment: What I meant by "worry about it" is that EST excludes EDT.  But of course, Eastern Time can be EDT or EST, so you may need to worry about that.  In the US, the time shifts at 2 am *local time*, so there is an hour each spring when the Eastern time zone is on EDT while the Central time zone is on CST, and in the fall there's an hour when EST coexists with CDT.  During the fall hour, civil time in New York and Chicago are equal; during the spring hour, they are removed by two hours.  But if you restrict yourself to business hours, then New York and Chicago are always one hour different.

Comment: After looking into the framework's `TimeZoneInfo` class a bit, I see that it confuses matters by having a single object called "Eastern Standard Time" whose `SupportsDaylightSavingTime` property is true.  If you pass "Eastern Daylight Time", you get an exception.  This is inconsistent with proper civil time terminology, but it reflects the commonly-held misconception that Eric Lippert's blog entry is trying to correct.

Comment: thanks for the insights... for my purposes i am dealing with times during the entire day not just business hours. so i think im still left with the problem. is there any way to adapt my code to adjust for daylight savings ?

Comment: Are you sure you can't eliminate times between 2AM and 3AM eastern time, on the second Sunday of March and the first Sunday of November?  If you can't, it would be simplest to use DateTimeOffset and forget about time zones, if that suits your needs.  If a time is expressed as UTC-5, does it matter to you whether it is EST or CDT?

Comment: Furthermore, why do you think your code isn't handling daylight saving time?  I just did a quick test, and `ConvertTimeToUtc` did in fact behave differently depending on whether the time I passed was in the summer or winter.  Please edit your question to include a working example that illustrates your problem, along with the result you expect and the actual result.

Comment: phoog thank you based on your comment if daylight savings changes only occur on sundays  then i can disregard sundays as i am writing a trading program and there are no trades on sundays as exchanges are closed. is it safe to assume that daylight savings ONLY occur on sundays ??

Comment: Yes, in the USA at least, it is always at 2 AM local time on a Sunday.  Are you covering time zones other than the US Eastern and Central zones?

Comment: no only trading US exchanges .. its settled then thanks very much.

Comment: how do i set this question to answered ?

Comment: Someone has to answer it first.  I'll do that in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from your question what the problem is; you have not described the results your code produces nor your expected result.

Except for two periods each year, of an hour's duration each, Central and Eastern time are always one hour apart.  The exceptions are at the transitions into and out of daylight saving time.  At 2 AM EST, on the second Sunday of March, the Eastern time zone's clocks move to 3 AM EDT.  For the next 60 minutes, Eastern Time is two hours ahead of Central Time.  Then, at 2 AM CST, the Central time zone's clocks move to 3 AM CDT, and the difference returns to one hour.

Similarly, on the first Sunday in November, at 2 AM EDT, clocks are set to 1 AM EST.  For the next 60 minutes, the Central zone remains on daylight saving time, so the time in both places is the same.  An hour later, the Central zone's clocks move back one hour, and the normal time difference is restored.

Since your times will never fall in either of these periods, you can safely assume that Central times are always one hour before Eastern times.